GNUAutomake: Can a target be added to `target_SOURCES`
Let's say I would like to build a target foo that depends on another target bar (which could be anything). How can I achieve this in Automake syntax?
Simply adding the target to foo_SOURCES in Makefile.am does not work
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = bar foo.c

bar: 
    do stuff

I can achieve what I want in a regular Makefile
foo: bar foo.c
    gcc ...

bar:
    do stuff

